# Why is comparing NOT (x= 0) and NOT (x = NULL) returning the same values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

With the following data:

```
ItemID      PrivateSales            PublicSales             TotalSales                   SalesPerson
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ---------------------------- -----------------------------
1           300                     400                     700                          12
1           NULL                    10                      10                           12
2           NULL                    NULL                    NULL                         NULL
3           NULL                    NULL                    NULL                         NULL
6           20                      900                     920                          11
8           22                      18                      40                           10
9           20                      980                     1000                         11
22          NULL                    NULL                    NULL                         NULL
11          NULL                    NULL                    NULL                         NULL
15          40                      NULL                    40                           77
16          12                      NULL                    12                           NULL
44          NULL                    44                      44                           23
```

When I run the following two different queries, I get the exact same results:

```
 SELECT TOP 1000 [ItemID]
    ,[PrivateSales]
    ,[PublicSales]
    ,[TotalSales]
    ,[SalesPerson]
FROM [Sales]
WHERE NOT (
    PrivateSales IS NULL
    AND PublicSales IS NULL
    AND TotalSales IS NULL
    )
```

AND:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [ItemID]
    ,[PrivateSales]
    ,[PublicSales]
    ,[TotalSales]
    ,[SalesPerson]
FROM [Sales]
WHERE NOT (
    PrivateSales = 0
    AND PublicSales = 0
    AND TotalSales = 0
    )
```

Considering the `NULL` columns, why is the `WHERE NOT (x = 0)` not returning the `NULL` columns?
The *Sales columns are decimal types if that matters.

Comment: **`NULL` with `<>, !=, =, <, >` is always NULL. Period.** `NOT (x=0)` is the same as `x <> 0` so when x is NULL it won't be returned back. For comparing with NULL use `IS NULL/IS NOT NULL`

Comment: At least on SQLAnywhere (and I guess ASE) there is an option called ansinull which is changing this for compat. reasons. I don't know MS SQL but maybe it's related to it. (So changing behavior away from stadard SQL)

Comment: Yes, there is [SET ANSI_NULLS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx), but please leave it alone. `When SET ANSI_NULLS is ON, a SELECT statement that uses WHERE column_name = NULL returns zero rows even if there are null values in column_name.`

Comment: Never wanted to say it's good, but might explain the behavior above.

Answer (score 1):

See this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29) for nulls,

comparing any true or false value with null results in null , effectively you are to negating a null which does not yield true or false
It is not returning null values as null is undetermined so it is not fulfilling condition that it is not equal to 0 or equal to 0 (it is unknown)

comparing NOT (x= 0) and NOT (x = NULL) should be

```
 NOT (x= 0) And x is not null
```

or

```
x<>0 and x is not null
```

reiterating lad2025's comment

"NULL with <>, !=, =, <, > is always NULL. Period. NOT (x=0) is the same as x <> 0"

Answer (score 1):

The *Law of Excluded Middle*, that is to say that **A or NOT A** being a tautology, is lost with introduction of the third truth value NULL. SQL Server's implementation of this fact is to interpret a Boolean NULL as UNKNOWN; to propagate UNKNOWN; and to coalesce UNKNOWN to FALSE unless an explicit test against UNKNOWN, aka NULL, has been performed.